# TableRows height won't come out right

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm trying to build a chess app, but I can't get the board to work correctly.  I have tried everything to make the Table row height match the column width so that the squares look square, but on different screens, they come out squished or stretched.

Here is my XML code:

```
    <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/chessboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background" >

    <!-- LINE 8 -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/line_8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="30dp" >

        <!-- NOTATION LINE 8 LEFT -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notation_8_left"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="#FEFEFE" />

        <!-- CELLS -->

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/a8"
            android:background="#fe9"
            android:onClick="moveClickHandler" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/brook"
            android:tag="br" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b8"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fb3"
            android:onClick="moveClickHandler"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/bknight"
            android:tag="bn" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/c8"
            android:background="#fe9"
            android:onClick="moveClickHandler" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/bbishop"
            android:tag="bb" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/d8"
            android:background="#fb3"
            android:onClick="moveClickHandler" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/bqueen"
            android:tag="bq" />
    ...
   </TableRow>
```

And here is my programmatic attempt to read the screen width and set the row height accordingly:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
squareWidth = size.x / 10;
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, squareWidth);
    TableRow rank8 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.line_8);rank8.setLayoutParams(params);
    TableRow rank7 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.line_7);rank7.setLayoutParams(params);
    TableRow rank6 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.line_6);rank6.setLayoutParams(params);
    TableRow rank5 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.line_5);rank5.setLayoutParams(params);
    TableRow rank4 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.line_4);rank4.setLayoutParams(params);
    TableRow rank3 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.line_3);rank3.setLayoutParams(params);
    TableRow rank2 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.line_2);rank2.setLayoutParams(params);
    TableRow rank1 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.line_1);rank1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

When I out-print the values of the heights and "squareWidth," I get "squareWidth is 160" but "Row height is 90" or "squareWidth is 35, row height is 68".  So it feels like Android is just making up whatever value it wants.  How can I force the rows to be the right height?!

Comment: I suspect that most chess apps would not be using a `TableLayout` in the first place, but rather would be using the 2D Canvas graphics API and simply drawing the desired board.

Comment: I should have started with something else, but I've come so far, and I fear it's too late to start over.  Everything works and is ready to go EXCEPT this problem!  So how can I force the rows to be a given height, every time, without fail?  Do I have the wrong parameters or something?

Answer (score 0):

In the XML you set:

```
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="35dp"
```

Why not:

```
 android:layout_height="35dp" android:layout_width="35dp"
```

(Also, why do you specify layout_weight? That shouldn't be there.)

Comment: You're reading for the row's children.  They fill their parent, the row.  I need to change the row height, and the children will grow with them.  The row is set to warp content, but then they are changed programmatically with LayoutParams anyway.  The weight is so they will evenly fill the screen's width.  Otherwise, they'll just bunch up on the left side of the screen.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you're trying to draw. Screens are not square. Are you trying to make the board fill the screen as much as possible?

Comment: In your code, why not: LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(squareWidth, squareWidth);

Comment: I am trying to get the board to be square, not the screen.  I want it to measure the screen width and then set the board height to that same measurement.  My problem is that even though I get the correct value for squareWidth (it prints out correctly), the rows are not being assigned that height.  I must be doing something wrong with my LayoutParams.

Comment: Use the same width for the height and width of the LayoutParams, as I indicated.

Comment: That doesn't work.  They just fill the parent, for some reason.  I don't think you can change the row heights programmatically.  I tried applying a LinearLayoutParams to the TableLayout, and that worked, but now I have to figure out how to get the last row to be the correct size, which is different from the rest.